# how to remove Project which accidently has been converted to branch on TFS

Tags: tfs

I have accidently converted my Project root to Branch.
say $/Project-1 is now shown as Branch how can i remove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to **File** menu-->Source Control-->Branching and Merging-->Click **Convert to Folder** option.

Comment: If this option is not visible on the menu, it is likely that you don't have the necessary permissions.